# Accessing Controller Class (Object) of JavaFX by Scene object from other classes

Tags: java, javafx

I am loading scenes from FXML and store the scenes in a Deque for changing menus. The FXML files are linked to controller classes.

I want to know is there any way to access controller class (Actually controller instance) of scene from scene?

For example is there any way to do something like this:

```
Scene scene = scenes.getLast();
scene.getController(); //There is no such method by default
```

(`scenes` is a `Deque` that stores Scene Objects)

Comment: Nope, unless you store the controller e.g. in the `userData` property when loading which would allow you to store this data in a more convenient data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fabian said, I would throw the controller into [Scene#userData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-).

In fact I use the userData property quite a bit for managing my views, stages, etc. -- mostly as an "id" of sorts for accessing them.